# Add COUNTBLANK to my formula, or another way

Tags: excel, count

I need to count the blank fields of a column that meets other perimeters, I'm using COUNTIF to find all those other critera but cannot for the life of me get blank fields to get counted! Here is what I've got so Far (minus the criteria for the last range)

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!N3:N5000, ">"&J2, Sheet2!N3:N5000, "<"&K2,Sheet2!M3:M5000,"Successful",Sheet2!O2:O5000,XXXX)
```

Can I add the COUNTBLANK to this formula, if so how? If not, how would I go about counting those blank fields...

I'm already using CountIFS as you can see, other COUNTBLANK formulas suggested on the forum are not friendly with my current formula...

Comment: so you need to replace the "XXXX" with a criteria that says *and column O is blank* ?

Comment: That's correct!
But I need to find the only the cells that are blank in column O.

Comment: Use `""` or `TEXT(,)` as the criteria for Sheet2!O2:O5000. You can also use full column references without penalty in a COUNTIFS.

Comment: The TEXT(,) worked, wasn't sure why the " " wasn't working though... Thanks!!!

Comment: You also have a typo in your formula. You cannot have Sheet2!O2:O5000 along with Sheet2!N3:N5000 and Sheet2!M3:M5000. They all have to be the same size. Change O2 to O3 or change N2 and M2 to N3 and M3.